# How to set compiler for LAPACK on linux with CMake?

Tags: linux, cmake, lapack

I want to compile LAPACK with the ifort compiler on linux using CMake. Or if that is not possible, at least how to do it with the Make system. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Which LAPACK implementation?

Comment: @AlexReinking 3.7.0, 3.10.1

Comment: That doesn't answer my question... are you compiling the Netlib LAPACK, or the OpenBLAS LAPACK, or something else?

Comment: I am using Netlib's  LAPACK.